# VBA Syntax errors

Tags: vba, syntax, ms-word, word-2010

I want to override the Word 2010 standard quick styles with my own. But I get an error as shown below:

```
With tempDoc.Styles(wdStyleNormal) '// <-- here is the error
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = 10
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
        .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 12
End With
```

You can find the whole code here: http://qranberry.com/stackoverflow/code.bas

Comment: Please, highlight the place in your code where messages occur e.x. "~~~> here is an error" .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 12

Comment: tempDoc is wrong i have written ActiveDocument instead, and at the end of the VBA code i deleted this line "tempDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges" then everythind worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the **document** like below .. Code tested and working fine in my system

```
Sub test()
Dim tempDoc As Document 
Set tempDoc = ActiveDocument
With tempDoc.Styles(wdStyleNormal) ' or u can use activedocument instead of tempdoc 
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = 30
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
        .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 12
End With
End Sub
```